# Finding extrinsics between cameras

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision, bundler, levenberg-marquardt

I'm in the situation where I need to find the relative camera poses between two/or more cameras based on image correspondences (so the cameras are not in the same point). To solve this I tried the same approach as described [here](http://www.morethantechnical.com/2012/02/07/structure-from-motion-and-3d-reconstruction-on-the-easy-in-opencv-2-3-w-code/) (code below).

```
cv::Mat calibration_1 = ...;
cv::Mat calibration_2 = ...;
cv::Mat calibration_target = calibration_1;
calibration_target.at<float>(0, 2) = 0.5f * frame_width;  // principal point
calibration_target.at<float>(1, 2) = 0.5f * frame_height; // principal point

auto fundamental_matrix = cv::findFundamentalMat(left_matches, right_matches, CV_RANSAC);
fundamental_matrix.convertTo(fundamental_matrix, CV_32F);
cv::Mat essential_matrix = calibration_2.t() * fundamental_matrix * calibration_1;
cv::SVD svd(essential_matrix);
cv::Matx33f w(0,-1,0,
    1,0,0,
    0,0,1);
cv::Matx33f w_inv(0,1,0,
    -1,0,0,
    0,0,1);
cv::Mat rotation_between_cameras = svd.u * cv::Mat(w) * svd.vt; //HZ 9.19
```

But in most of my cases I get extremly weird results. So my next thought was using a full fledged bundle adjuster (which should do what i am looking for?!). Currently my only big dependency is OpenCV and they only have a undocumented bundle adjustment implementation.

So the question is:

- Is there a bundle adjuster which has no dependencies and uses a licence which allows commerical use?
- Are there other easy way to find the extrinsics?
- Are objects with very different distances to the cameras a problem? (heavy parallax)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you provide more details? Do, both cameras have a common Field of View (FOV) ?

Comment: The cameras are the same model - but not identical - so the intrinsics could be slightly different. Ideally the the intrinsics get adjusted too but this is currently not my priority

Comment: My question was whether both cameras have a common area that can be imaged. If yes, you can place a chessboard in that common area and find the relative pose between cameras.

Comment: The cameras have an overlap of ~30% of the horizontal FOV but i cant use chessboards or any other pattern - my input are feature correspondences

Answer (score 1):

I'm also working on same problem and facing slimier issues.
Here are some suggestions -

1. Modify Essential Matrix Before Decomposition:
   Modify Essential matrix before decomposition [U W Vt] = SVD(E), and new E' = diag(s,s,0) where s = W(0,0) + W(1,1) / 2
2. 2-Stage Fundamental Matrix Estimation:
   Recalculate the fundamental matrix with the RANSAC inliers

These steps should make the Rotation estimation more susceptible to noise.

Comment: hey thanks for your answer, can you explain step one with a bit more detail?

Answer (score 0):

you have to get 4 different solutions and select the one with the most # points having positive Z coordinates. The solution are generated by inverting the sign of the fundamental matrix an substituting w with w_inv which you did not do though you calculated w_inv. Are you reusing somebody else code?